# Hyperledger Fabric: ClientHandshake Error: Client TLS handshake failed with error: EOF remoteaddress=[::1]:7051

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying using the Hyperledger Fabric tutorial to use the test network in the provided fabric samples. I've successfully installed all the prerequisites and started the network, but when I try to create a channel, it throws a ClientHandshake error.

Relevant page of the tutorial: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test_network.html 
Github link where you can see the test-network: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/test-network

I'm using macOS Big Sur [2020 MacBook Pro], and followed the macOS instructions in the tutorial.

Error message:

```
...
Channel 'mychannel' created
Joining org1 peer to the channel...
Using organization 1
+ peer channel join -b ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block
+ res=1
+ peer channel join -b ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block
+ res=1
+ peer channel join -b ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block
+ res=1
+ peer channel join -b ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block
+ res=1
2021-06-10 19:38:34.968 IST [comm.tls] ClientHandshake -> ERRO 001 Client TLS handshake failed after 1.178599ms with error: EOF remoteaddress=[::1]:7051
2021-06-10 19:38:35.972 IST [comm.tls] ClientHandshake -> ERRO 002 Client TLS handshake failed after 1.881928ms with error: EOF remoteaddress=[::1]:7051
2021-06-10 19:38:37.503 IST [comm.tls] ClientHandshake -> ERRO 003 Client TLS handshake failed after 2.60866ms with error: EOF remoteaddress=[::1]:7051
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to localhost:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
After 5 attempts, peer0.org1 has failed to join channel 'mychannel'
```

Is this something to do with the TLS certificates? I came across two questions which might be relevant, except that they're about a ServerHandshake error:

1. [Hyperledger Fabric: ServerHandshake TLS handshake bad certificate server=PeerServer AND ServerHandshake TLS handshake EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62495170/hyperledger-fabric-serverhandshake-tls-handshake-bad-certificate-server-peerser)
2. [Hyperledger Fabric How to generate peer sans certificates via fabric-ca-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62529227/hyperledger-fabric-how-to-generate-peer-sans-certificates-via-fabric-ca-client)

Any solution clearly explaining what steps I should take to resolve this error would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to incorrect mapping of ports for all the peers, orderers, couchdb and other containers (if any).

Always use correct mapping for ports.

example -
orderer
- 7050:7050
- 17050:17050

peer1
- 9051:9051
- 19051:19051
peer2
- 9061:9061
- 19061:19061